# Как правильно расставить отношения OneToMany - ManyToOne?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть две сущности новости и категории. Создаю отношение в сущности news к category:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private int category;
```

Многое к одному, то есть многим записям может соответствовать 1 категория.
К примеру мне нужно чтобы было именно отношение News.category-> Category.id.
То есть я проставил в базе цифру 1 что соответствует 1 категории, ниже скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сущность Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Проект собирается, но при запросе на сервер вылетает ошибка -

```
HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error].

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [com.reweu.server.entity.Category@2e9827b7] value by reflection : [class com.reweu.server.entity.News.category] setter of com.reweu.server.entity.News.category; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [com.reweu.server.entity.Category@2e9827b7] value by reflection : [class com.reweu.server.entity.News.category] setter of com.reweu.server.entity.News.category
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина.

Comment: нельзя использовать mappedBy и JoinColumn одновременно

Comment: я совсем запутался видимо.

Comment: сократите пример. оставьте только то, что нужно для демонстрации проблемы. добавьте описание схемы БД.

Comment: Не знаю в чем нарисовать схему, а так текст сократил

Comment: слишком сократили. попробуйте вот это сделать [mcve]. нарисовать можно этим http://plantuml.com/

Comment: Михаил еще раз поправил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодиться. 
Разобрался, у меня ошибка в `private int category;`
Надо так:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private Сategory category;
```